# Location of entrust roles and permissions code

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I am new to Laravel and trying to use enrtust plugin for roles and permissions, but when following the instructions in the documentation, I reached the bit where I have to put the code that creates the roles and permissions, but it did not mention where I have to put it. What is the best place to put it?

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
$owner = new Role();
$owner->name         = 'owner';
$owner->display_name = 'Project Owner'; // optional
$owner->description  = 'User is the owner of a given project'; // 
$owner->save();

$admin = new Role();
$admin->name         = 'admin';
$admin->display_name = 'User Administrator'; // optional
$admin->description  = 'User is allowed to manage and edit other users'; 
$admin->save();
```

Comment: yeah their documentation is not great, you can put this in a controller and run it once to make the roles if you want, you could also do this in artisan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/seeding) for this situation. In this example I create `RoleTableSeeder`, `PermissionTableSeeder` and `PermissionRoleTableSeeder`.

You can run seeder separately with this command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionTableSeeder
```

or you can run all seeder by this command:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: is there any difference between using seeder or a controller that i run only once ?

Comment: @theinquisitor Not in execution. But with console/terminal you are owner of that process and can not be unintentionally requested by someone over browser.